# Change Genexus logger

Tags: logging, genexus

As far as I know Genexus is using Log4J by default in Java applications, but if I wanted to change the logger and use like for example Logback, can I do it? If so, how?

I'm using Genexus 16 U10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my knowledge, Genexus logging function is coded in a specific way for Log4J, so it gets really hard to change it to something else. I'm not sure why would you ever need to change it but maybe take a look at [Genexus' GitHub](https://github.com/genexuslabs/JavaClasses/blob/master/common/src/main/java/com/genexus/diagnostics/Log.java)